# Weight in cts:element-range-query

Tags: marklogic

The weight parameter to cts:element-range-query is not affecting the sequence of outcome.

Below is the document that contains a sample document and a range query with weight implemented, But with no effect on order whatsoever. Could you please tell us the how can we make sure that different values of weight when passed to range query would provide different sequence of output records.

```
Create a document /dates.xml in Mraklogic with some data:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<entry>
<date>2007-01-01</date >
enter code here
<info>Some information.</info>
</entry>
<entry>
<date>2006-06-23</date>
<info>Some other information.</info>
</entry>
<entry>
<date>1971-12-23</date>
<info>Some different information.</info>
</entry>
</root>
```

Create a range index on date  with datatype as Date. 
Now try running the query:

```
cts:search(fn:doc("/dates.xml")/root/entry,
  cts:or-query((
    cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("date"), ">=",
      xs:date("2007-01-01"),(),-16),
    cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("date"), "=",
      xs:date("2006-06-23"),(),+16))))
```

Any change in weight parameter results in same sequence of records

Answer (score 2):

All the `entry` elements in `dates.xml` are part of the same document. So they all share the same index entries and have the same scoring information. That's why changing the weights doesn't change the results. You can confirm that using `cts:score`.

MarkLogic is a document-oriented database. It indexes documents. Format your XML so that each documents acts like a row in a relational database. Avoid creating large documents that try to act like tables. In this case I would create one document per `entry` element. Then query term weights should work as expected.

One way to force yourself into this is to simplify your call to `cts:search`: just use `doc()` or `collection()`, and put all the constraints in the second parameter as a `cts:query`. That what it's obvious that you are searching for entire documents that match.

It's also possible to use sub-fragments, but I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

Range queries do not contribute to score at all by default. You need to use the score-function parameter to choose to have non-zero scoring.